# Is there a way to calculate proportions by groups?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to calculate the following proportion for each city: mean(age < 25).

My code so far is the following:

```
namevar <- data %>% group_by(city) %>% mean (age < 25).
```

My data is clean and has no NA.

If I use mean(age <25) it works, but when I use the group_by function it doesn't.

This is the message that appears:

> In mean.default(unlist(x, use.names = FALSE, recursive = TRUE),  :
> argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

Thanks a lot for reading and helping :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `mutate` (if we want to create a new column) or `summarise` (if needed to summarise)

```
library(dplyr)
data1 <-  data %>%
       group_by(city) %>%
       summarise(Prop = mean(age < 25))
```

Comment: When I do that I only get the proportion of the whole data set, not by city

Comment: @JuanGuillermoMichelsen have you loaded `plyr` as well?  In that case use `dplyr::summarise(Prop = mean(age < 25))` because there can be masking of function